# logical or expression c++

Tags: c++, operators, expression

I have a problem using the Logical OR operator in C++. The problem is coming that the right-side expression is not evaluated if the left-side is true. I have two deque-s and I need to popLeft from them with a while, but if I can pop from the first deque, I don't pop from the second because is not evaluated, by the OR operator. How can I overcome this problem. Here is the piece of code:

```
while( D.popLeft( k ) || E.popLeft( m ) )
{
    if( k < m )
    {
      C.pushRight( k );
      E.pushLeft( m );
    }
    else
    {
      C.pushRight( m );
      D.pushLeft( k );
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a "problem"; that's a feature.

Comment: can u explain in detail?

Comment: @KirilKirov: Surely that potentially breaks the loop condition, though it's not entirely clear yet as to what that condition _is_

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you only want to run the content of the loop when you can fill both m and k, right? Then simply replace your OR with an AND:

```
while( D.popLeft( k ) && E.popLeft( m ) )
{
    if( k < m )
    {
      C.pushRight( k );
      E.pushLeft( m );
    }
    else
    {
      C.pushRight( m );
      D.pushLeft( k );
    }
}
```

Then both pops will be executed.

Comment: Yeah, so stupid of me, it's very simple! Thanks guys, sorry for the stupid question :-D

Comment: If it worked out for you, you could consider accepting one of the correct answers as the solution (by pressing the tick mark). That way, people who stumble upon this question later have a clear indication of what's a good way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to keep your `||` (and not use a `&&`), you can evaluate separatly:

```
bool canPopE = E.popLeft( m );
bool canPopD = D.popLeft( k );
bool canPop = canPopD || canPopE;

while( canPop )
{
    if( k < m )
    {
      C.pushRight( k );
      E.pushLeft( m );
    }
    else
    {
      C.pushRight( m );
      D.pushLeft( k );
    }

    canPopE = E.popLeft( m );
    canPopD = D.popLeft( k );
    canPop = canPopD || canPopE;
}
```

Comment: While this does maintain the OR-condition, it lays root for the more disturbing issue of calling on k and m while they are not freshly popped. Strictly speaking you're correct, and this is a decent way to maintain the logic, but I'm fairly confident the question-asker intended something different. One can't say for sure, though, as the OP's intentions are not entirely clear.

Comment: @Joost I totally agree, just provided a straight solution to the question asked (i.e. popping both sides).

Answer (score 0):

use `&&` operator

```
while( D.popLeft( k ) && E.popLeft( m ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

By default C++ logical operators use short circuit mechanism, if you want to do your loop without short circuit, use eager operator "|" instead. This will evaluate both expressions any way.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

```
while( D.popLeft( k ) | E.popLeft( m ) )
```

Comment: This while that I use is for merging two sorted Deques in one sorted Deque. But I face difficulty trying to do it. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: So, can you pleas change your question to show what you want to say?