# Why does logical OR operator not evaluating the parenthesized right hand side condition first?

Tags: c++

Consider the code:

```
int i=2, j=3;
if(i<5 or (++i==j))
    cout << "i=" << i;
```

The output is:

```
i=2
```

Why not using parenthesis have any effect in the above condition? Why not the output is 3?

```
compiler: g++ 4.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04LTS
```

Comment: This is called short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: Because it is, by design, one of the four C/C++ operators that produce [sequence points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

Comment: Also, don't confuse operator precedence with evaluation order, and parentheses do not affect evaluation order.

Comment: Since `i<5` is true, the `(++i==j)` part won't be reached.

Comment: `or` is technically legal, but seriously unconventional to most C++ programmers.  Everyone uses `||`.

Comment: Use `|` in order to do non short-circuit evaluation (although I don't recommend doing that).

Comment: Duplicate of [logical or expression c++:  the right-side expression is not evaluated if the left-side is true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668643/logical-or-expression-c)

Comment: @MarounMaroun: | ain't a sequence point. The compiler has just eaten your cat.

Comment: @Bathsheba Doesn't this work the same way it does in Java?

Comment: Not at all. i < 5 | (++i==j) is undefined in C++.

Comment: @Bathsheba Then how do you beak laziness in logical conditions?

Comment: The UB is caused by your writing and reading i in an unsequenced block.

Comment: Plenty of SO questions on this. Google the boiled-down version i = ++i;

Comment: @Bathsheba What's the meaning of "The compiler has just eaten your cat"? :D

Comment: A compiler is allowed to do anything when it encounters an undefined construct.

Answer (score 6):

`or` is the same as `||`, which performs a short-circuit evaluation from left to right. This means that once the result of the expression containing `||` is known, evaluation stops.

(`||` is also a sequencing point, so the behaviour is well-defined even in the case where `i >= 5`).

Since `i < 5` is `true`, the other expression is not computed; so `i` is not incremented.

Comment: "*This means that once the result is known, evaluation stops*" - It should be evaluated to true in order to stop, otherwise the other part *will* be evaluated.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Note that the lhs being false means that the result of the entire expression is not known yet.  If the lhs is true, then the result of `lhs || rhs` is *know*, and evaluation can stop.

Comment: @Yakk I thought Bathsheba was referring the result of the `lhs`, maybe I was wrong.